# How to show option name in Ant Design Select when using setFieldsValue

Tags: multi-select, antd, rc-form

I'm using a  component from Ant Design and recently I added a button to select all options. The functionality is ok but in the field it shows the option keys or ids instead of showing the option names.

My question is, is there any way to show the option names when using setFieldsValue method in a multi-select component?

I have tried pushing an object with different properties (id, name, key, value, title, etc) in this part `selecteds.push(kid.id);` but none of those works.

My select funtion looks like this

```js
selectAllKids = () => {
    const { kids } = this.props;
    let selecteds = [];

    kids.map(kid => {
      selecteds.push(kid.id);
    });

    this.props.form.setFieldsValue({
      kids: selecteds
    });
  };
```

and my component:

```js
         {getFieldDecorator("kids", {
          rules: [
            {
              required: true,
              message: "Selecciona alumnos"
            }
          ]
        })(
          <Select
            size="large"
            mode="multiple"
            placeholder="Selecciona alumnos"
            loading={kidsLoading}
          >
            {kids.map(kid => (
              <Option key={kid.id}>{kid.name}</Option>
            ))}
          </Select>
        )}
```

My current result is:
[image]
My expected result is:
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Better create a producible example that posting images [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: try keeping `selecteds` in state. Update the state when you want to select all the values. Add this `value={selecteds}` in `Select`. See if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should map to `name` and not to `id`:

```
this.props.form.setFieldsValue({
  kids: kids.map(({ name }) => name)
});
```

[image: Edit Q-58788999-SelectAllInForm]

Comment: it only helps to display but when getting the value will be wrong, how to fix this? thanks

Comment: Please ask separate question and tag me, we need more context, add reproducible example

Comment: The context is the same as the question above, but I found the answer by adding `value` to `Option`, thanks for the help